# jQuery Functions On AJAX Loaded Content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an unordered list that is being loaded from an external file using `$.get()`. Once that is loaded, the unordered list needs to be manipulated using `.show()` (it is display: none; by default) when the page loads.

After reading many explanations, I understand why `show()` is not working on the loaded content. They say that you need to use `live()` (well, now `.on()`) to attach the a handler to an event, but all the examples are things like clicking and mousing over.

Ajax call:

```
$.get('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nascar_plaza/inc/sidebar_login.php', function(data) {
    $('#site-header-nav-container > ul > li:last-child').append(data);
});
```

jQuery to run on loaded content:

```
$('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu').css({
    display: 'block',
    width: '235px'
});
$('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu li').show();
```

Can someone give me an example on how to get the code above to run on the content after it has been loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like you said it: "Run after it's loaded"

```
var url = '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nascar_plaza/inc/sidebar_login.php'

$.get(url, function(data) {

    //anything in this block runs after the ajax call

    $('#site-header-nav-container > ul > li:last-child').append(data);

    $('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu').css({ 
        display: 'block', 
        width: '235px' 
    }); 

    $('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu li').show(); 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The second part of your code (css manipulation and displaying the list) should go inside the callback function, which runs after the data is loaded.

```
$.get('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/nascar_plaza/inc/sidebar_login.php', function(data) {

   $('#site-header-nav-container > ul > li:last-child').append(data);

   $('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu').css({
       display: 'block',
       width: '235px'
   }).find('li').show();

});
```

Comment: +1, nice chaining. You could make it more efficient by chaining it off of the `.append()`, like this: `.append(data).find('.current-menu-ancestor .sub-menu').css({ display : 'block', width : '235px' }).find('li').show();`

Comment: Err, so easy! There seams to be a noticeable performance loss doing this. You can see the element pop in when it gets shown. Any way to get around this? I guess it's from it loading, but the file is only a few lines of html.